# When user returns to previous canvas

Tags: oracle, location, oracleforms

I’m new to Oracle Form 12c. I’m trying to get the cursor to return back to the location it was when the user returns to that canvas from another canvas.  How would I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

That "location" is, basically, the **item**.

It means that you'll first have to "remember" where you were; to do so, use `:SYSTEM.TRIGGER_ITEM` system variable and store its value into a parameter or a global variable.

Then do whatever you're doing and - once you're done - navigate back to item you *saved* using the `GO_ITEM` built-in.